# Cannot reproduce well-known summation result

Tags: bugs, summation

**Bug introduced in 4.2 or 5.0, persisting through 13.0.0.**

---

Note: this is a repost of [my OP on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940574/on-an-identity-that-appears-in-ap%C3%A9rys-proof-of-the-irrationality-of-zeta3). I am posting it here because multiple users with different Mathematica versions have given me the feedback that they also have the same incorrect behaviour while evaluating the sum below. The following paragraphs are basically a copy paste of the OP, for those who don't want to click.

---

In proving the irrationality of $\displaystyle \zeta(3)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^3}$, Apéry introduced the accelerated series

$$
\zeta(3)=\frac{5}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}} {\binom {2k}{k}k^{3}}}.
$$

A crucial ingredient of his proof of the above identity is the well-known equality
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!^2}{(n^2-1^2)\ldots(n^2-k^2)}=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}.
$$
(note that an excellent overview of his proof can be found in Van der Poorten's "[A Proof that Euler Missed...](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf)".)

---

I was trying to verify the above equality numerically, in Wolfram Mathematica. However, when asking to evaluate the LHS, Mathematica surprisingly gave:

```
1/n^2
```

This is obviously false, as quick numerical verification reveals.

This was the simple Mathematica instruction I ran:

```
Clear[n]
N[Sum[((-1)^(k - 1) ((k - 1)!)^2)/(Product[(n^2 - j^2), {j, 1, k}]), {k, 1, n - 1}]]
```

Note that Wolfram Alpha gives the same incorrect evaluation for the same expression, as can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BSum%5B%28%28-1%29%5E%28k%20-%201%29%20%28%28k%20-%201%29%21%29%5E2%29%2F%28Product%5B%28n%5E2%20-%20j%5E2%29%2C%20%7Bj%2C%201%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20k%7D%5D%29%2C%20%7Bk%2C%201%2C%20n%20-%201%7D%5D%5D).

---

So what am I doing wrong? Clearly, the instruction itself is correct (click the Alpha link to see this). So is the Wolfram engine making an elementary mistake, or am I doing so?

Comment: @MarcoB OK thank you.

Comment: Klangen I am unfamiliar with the formula itself, but numerical test validation agrees with your result over a wide range of n. I think you are right to say that it is a bug. I would encourage you to report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your comment

Comment: Another very old bug. _v4.1_ cannot solve it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQrYS.png _v5.0_ gives `(Csc[(n*Pi)/2]*Sec[(n*Pi)/2]*(-Pi + n^2*Pi + n*HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2 - n, 2 + n}, 1]*Sin[n*Pi]))/(2*(-1 + n)*n*(1 + n))`, whose limitation when `n` is an integer seems to be `1/n^2`:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/euQjw.png

Comment: `Product[(n^2 - j^2), {j, 1, k}]` in your simple Mathematica expression is always zero (for n integer)

Comment: Update: even using Mathematica's `Assuming[Element[n, Integers], ...]`, I still get the same incorrect result.

Comment: @Andreas I find that weird since none of the terms equal $0$ ($k$ runs at most up to $n-1$)

Comment: there seems to be a problem there: The product evaluates correctly to an expression with Pochhammer terms. But if you compare for instance `n = 4; Table[ Pochhammer[1 - n, k], {k, 1, n - 1}]` with `n = 4; Table[Gamma[1 + k - n]/Gamma[1 - n], {k, 1, n - 1}]` (obtained by applying FunctionExpand on the Pochhammer) the results are different.

Comment: @Andreas I agree. I have made similar computations that make it blindingly obvious that Mathematica is wrong. For instance, one can simply take the difference between the LHS and the RHS for various values of $n$, giving the correct result. However, when $n$ is NOT defined, it fails

Comment: Well, maybe off-topic, v12.2?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Yes, it's released, freely avaiable on Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate this issue, the difference between `1/n^2` and the result of the Sum becomes very small as `n` gets larger. Here for `n = 2 to 20`.

```
Table[N[1/n^2  - 
   Sum[((-1)^(k - 1) ((k - 1)!)^2)/(Product[(n^2 - j^2), {j, 1, 
        k}]), {k, 1, n - 1}], Infinity], {n, 2, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Since the symbolic sum fails, only evaluate the sum for numeric values of `n`

```
sum[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 sum[n] = Sum[(-1)^(k - 1) ((k - 1)!)^2/Product[n^2 - m^2, {m, 1, k}], {k, 1, 
    n - 1}]

f = 1/n^2 - 2 (-1)^(n - 1)/(n^2 Binomial[2 n, n]);

And @@ Table[f == sum[n], {n, 1, 200}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as it is. I suggest adding a big "## yes, it's a bug" header, at least.